# Ggplot2 y-axis gets inverted based on screen resolution/aspect ratio download

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an issue with geom_col plot, where the plot gets inverted based on screen size/resolution and when i ggsave it.

Here is a reprex for the problem

```
library(tidyverse)
#I am using ggplot2 v3.3.5

tibble(x4 = c(8.947916, 8.947798 ,8.947830, 8.947833, 
              8.947799 ,8.947827 ,8.947795, 8.947830, 8.947837),
       x5 = c("TT", "CC", "CC", "MM", "MM", "HH", "HH", "MH", "DD"))  %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = x5, y = x4) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(8.9478,8.9481)) -> p1

ggsave("bugplot.png", plot = p1) #This plot gets inverted. The same bug issue is also observed in shinyapp based on screen size/resolution. 

ggsave("goodplot.png",plot = p1, width = 10, height = 8, units = "cm") #Expected output
```

#### Good plot

[image: Good plot]

#### Bug plot

[image: Bug plot]

Its based on screen/plot panel size/resolution.
[Please click here to view gif which will show how to reproduce](https://i.ibb.co/LndMYc2/ezgif-3-487ead907d.gif)

Comment: What is the `scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ec761d","#008799"))` for Your plots din't display any colors

Comment: Can't reproduce this behaviour on my machine. Maybe first use: `dev.off()`